# Lottie Files in Next13 Beta: Importing .json animation / lottie animation

Tags: animation, next.js, import, lottie, next.js13

I am not sure the correct syntax to import my animation. I am using lottie-react library and it specifies to import the animation locally rather than from a url like the og lottie-player.

I get:

Cannot find module '/animations/loading-spinner.json' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

no matter what way I try to do it.

I have so far tried putting the .json file in a separate 'animations' folder inside of the 'public' folder. I have tried just having it in the public folder. I have also tried pulling the animations folder out to the root. Not sure what I am missing here.

```
import Lottie from "lottie-react";
import loadingSpinner from "../animations/loading-spinner.json";
```

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully loaded the lottie animation in my next app. You'll need a JSON loader to do this.

[image]

The data is loading correctly in the developer console

[image]

The correct lottie component:

```
npm i react-lottie
```

JSON Loader installer:

```
npm install --save-dev json-loader
```

Next step, you'll need to add the JSON loader to your webpack configuration file if you have one. If not, just create a "webpack.config.js" in your root folder and add the following code:

```
module.exports = {

   // Other config modules
   
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.json$/,
          use: 'json-loader',
        },
      ],
    },
  };
```

Keep it seperate from your other config modules. Also make sure the "LoadingSpinner" path is correct.

```
import React from "react";
import Lottie from "react-lottie";
import LoadingSpinner from "../animations/loading-spinner.json";

const MyLottieAnimation = () => {

console.log(LoadingSpinner);//Check developer console

  const options = {
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    animationData: LoadingSpinner,
    rendererSettings: {
      preserveAspectRatio: "xMidYMid slice",
    },
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Lottie options={options} height={400} width={400} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyLottieAnimation;
```

The JSON file should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes it was in my public folder. Yes the package is installed. I imported the file the way you are suggesting. 

I even tried with no animations folder just directly in ‘/public’ but no luck. 

Did you try replicating in Next 13 and it worked for you?

Comment: Console log the data to see if its being imported.

Comment: If you haven't solved it yet, try this.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Tested it and it works find.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have install following packages,

```
"dependencies": {
"prop-types": "^15.8.1",
"react-lottie": "^1.2.3"
....
},
"devDependencies": {
  "json-loader": "^0.5.7"
  ....
}
```

### Use:

```
import Lottie from "react-lottie";
import JsonFileData from "./lottiefiles/ringing2.json";
...

const defaultOptions = {
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    animationData: JsonFileData,
    rendererSettings: {
      preserveAspectRatio: "xMidYMid slice"
    }
  };
....
<Lottie options={defaultOptions} height={200} width={200} />
```